# Visual Basic problems when connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Me and my 'team' from our informatics class have been trying to get a program running and connecting it to a SQL server, it seems we keep getting errors. Could you help me try and figure out the problem, I have been trying to fix this for 3 straight days so any help is welcome.

Code we have so far:

```
    Try
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim test As String = 64012478
        conn.ConnectionString = "User ID=*****_****; Password=******; Initial Catalog=dainformat_idea; Data Source=(IP of website);"
        conn.Open()
        Dim query = "SELECT * From students"
        Dim commando As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = commando.ExecuteReader
        reader.Read()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            MessageBox.Show(reader(0) & " " & reader(1) & "Kaas")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find something")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try`
```

Comment: What errors do you receive?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to connect a SQL Server with the MySQL libraries... If you have mySQL on the server the code will run fine, but only if you have mysql, otherwise the connection will fail.